# Are there datasets to use to validate a correlation measure with only categorical variables?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, dataset

I created a correlation measure for categorical variables.
I am comparing my results against chi square test and LL (if two variables are dependent, I am assuming they are correlated as well). But I want to have some "golden" dataset that tells me which attributes should be correlated. I already searched in Weka and UCI.

Does anyone know if this kind of dataset exists? Or how can I create it?